# Teams-for-Linux can't connect with audio anymore

Tags: sound, microphone

My problem is similar to: "Webcam not working on Microsoft Teams, installed via snap".

I did the same routine as suggested there to install Teams with Snap. Initially there was sound and microphone but no camera.

Also something went wrong during installation as there was a notification that some packages were incomplete. After a new upgrade (I am using Ubuntu 18 LTS on a Dell Latitude 3340) I managed to fix this problem I connected the camera as suggested by doing: "snap connect teams-for-linux:camera core:camera".

This worked out OK; when I use Teams now the camera works , but now microphone and speakers are not connected anymore to Teams. 
I did check sound and mike: the speakers work alright in "speaker test", and microphone level indicator shows that sound is registered by the microphone.

- Could it be that, similar to camera, audio has also to be connected manually?  What would be the command to do so?
- Or is there an other cause for the problem?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the snap and installing teams via a .deb file? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/microsoft-teams/download-app#allDevicesSection To install issue: `sudo apt install ./path/to/.deb`

Comment: The same happened to me. I got the MS Teams installed from .deb. Out of the blue the mic did not work. The strangest thing is that the test works fine. It was just when I connected and was face to face with my client,
the sound disappeared. I guess this is just Microsoft having fun with Linux users. Uninstalled and using the Web client.